# make space between link button CSS

Tags: css

does anyone know how i can place some space between the buttons(buttons act as links)? i cant realy find an answer anywhere....

CSS code:

```
.btn {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
background: #447494;
padding: 6px 25px 6px 10px;
text-decoration: none;


.btn:hover {
background: #079ce6;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

[I want some space beteen the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65PRB.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Also, you're missing `}` after `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: Add your mark up too

Comment: You are looking for the [**margin**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property.

Answer (score 1):

Sample snippet to play around with is included below.

It should basically depend on how your markup is structured. In the below sample a new `class` is added to *highlight* the situation, but you could remove this class and add the property to `.btn`:

```css
.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
  box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #447494;
  padding: 6px 25px 6px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #079ce6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-space {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Button 1</div>
<div class="btn btn-space">Button 2 - give me some space!</div>
<div class="btn">Button 3</div>
<div class="btn">Button 4</div>
<div class="btn">Button 5</div>
<div class="btn">Button 5</div>
<div class="btn">Button 6</div>
<div class="btn">Button 7</div>
<div class="btn">Button 8</div>
<div class="btn">Button 9</div>
<div class="btn">Button 10</div>
```

---

**Edit** to the update on the question: **buttons act as links**

Make use of the display property like - `display: block;` or `display:inline-block` based on the requirement.

Sample with `anchor` tags:

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
  box-shadow: 6px 1px 18px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #447494;
  padding: 6px 25px 6px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #079ce6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-space {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">Button 1</a>
<a class="btn btn-space">Button 2 - give me some space!</a>
<a class="btn">Button 3</a>
<a class="btn">Button 4</a>
<a class="btn">Button 5</a>
<a class="btn">Button 5</a>
<a class="btn">Button 6</a>
<a class="btn">Button 7</a>
<a class="btn">Button 8</a>
<a class="btn">Button 9</a>
<a class="btn">Button 10</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn {
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Use margin to give space between element boundaries.